# react router + redux Warning: Location "xyz" did not match any routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux

I'm trying to make a routing in my react and redux application, but still not luck.

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createHistory } from 'history';

import DashboardApp from './containers/App';
import QuizApp from './containers/QuizApp';
import Page from './containers/Page';
import store from './store';

const routes = <Router history={createHistory()}>
    <Route path="/" component={Page}>
        <IndexRoute component={DashboardApp} />
        <Route path="quiz" component={QuizApp} />
    </Route>
</Router>;

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        {routes}
    </Provider>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Default view is generated properly. In `DashboardApp` I have code like:

```
<Link to='quiz'>Quiz</Link>
```

If I click on it I get error in console:

```
Warning: Location "quiz" did not match any routes
```

I would appreciate any hint how to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use absolute path instead of the name.

`<Link to='/quiz'>Quiz</Link>`

See Link component documentation as described [here](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/UPGRADE_GUIDE.md#links)